# Executing `flutter run` on a remote machine makes xcodebuild fail

Tags: xcode, flutter, xcodebuild

I am connected to a mac via ssh and physically connected an iPhone to it.
Now I wanted to run `flutter run` on that mac to test my app on the iPhone.

When logging in graphically on the mac, `flutter run` executes without a problem.

But over ssh, `flutter run` fails in the `xcodebuild` stage. It produces a generic error message

> Error output from Xcode build:
> 2022-06-07 08:39:37.623 xcodebuild[6002:21187] XType: com.apple.fonts is not accessible.
> 2022-06-07 08:39:37.623 xcodebuild[6002:21187] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled.
> ** BUILD FAILED **

> Xcode's output: 
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I was able to gather the following error message via `flutter run --verbose`

> Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign
>
> <project_folder>/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent

What is going on?

Why does the build fail when logged in over ssh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, `xcodebuild` required access to an item that has been stored in the login keychain.
When graphically logging in on the mac, the keychain has been automatically unlocked. But when only logged in over ssh, the keychain remains locked.

The keychain can be unlocked via the following command

```
security unlock-keychain login.keychain
```

Afterwards, `flutter run` succeeds